# How can I choose the number of lines of a text box? (*not* the height)

Tags: html, css

All the stuff I'm finding on google or Stackoverflow are about the *height* of the textbox, not the number of rows/lines.

I want to have a textbox with more than one line (for a "send a message" feature)

How can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: I want to use an input type="text", because I want to use it in a form.

Comment: What makes `input type="text"` any better than `textarea` when it comes to `form`'s?   Quote: _"I want to have a textbox with more than one line (for a 'send a message' feature)"_.  Yes, that's exactly why we have `textarea` elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use some simple maths...

```
number of lines = height / line height
```

So if you wanted two lines in your `textarea`...

```
textarea {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. What I meant by textbox was input type='text'. Is there any way of doing that? Thanks

Comment: @alexx0186 I don't think a `input[type="text"]` can show multiple lines of text. That is what the `textarea` element is for.

Answer (score 3):

```
<textarea name="text" rows="3"></textarea>
```

This will give you a textbox with 3 lines worth of height.

Comment: Yes, it would work. You can check this out by serializing a form that has a textarea in it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for textarea? They're multi-lined.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

You can do this:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="8">Text Goes Here</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since i'm using this in a form, I would like  it to be a input type='text'. Thanks a lot

Comment: @alexx0186, what are you talking about?  `textarea` is for `form`'s too.

Comment: Yes, I just figured that out. I was confused by the fact that it didn't have the input tag. Thanks for clarifying